# How to make python code go back to the original question after it hits the else or elif in an if else statement instead of quitting the code

Tags: python

For example:

```
if answer == "1":
    print ("right answer")

elif answer == "2":
    print ("Wrong answer. Try again")

else:
    print ("Invalid input: Please try again")
```

So that was just a quick example of what I'm trying to say. Instead of allowing the user to enter the answer again, the code quits and they have to go through the whole thing.

How can I make it so that they get to return to the original answer instead of starting the entire code over again?

Thank you.

EDIT: I should have used the actual code instead of an example because I can't understand it in the context of my actual code.

```
print ("\nYou do not have any dogs treats. Maybe you should have grabbed some--your mother always keeps the dog treats in one of the bedrooms upstairs.")
                next_choice = input("\nWhat do you do now?\n1. Go back upstairs and get the dog treats\n2. Walk down anyway\n")
                
                if next_choice == "1":
                    which_bedroom = input ("\nYou go back upstairs to look for the dog treats. Which room do you go to first?\n1. Your bedroom\n2. Your sister's bedroom\n3. The bathroom\n4. Your mother's bedroom\n")
                    
                    if which_bedroom == "1":
                        print ("This is where you first started. There is nothing here. Please try again.")
                    
                    elif which_bedroom == "2":
                        print ("There is nothing here. Please try again.")

                    elif which_bedroom == "3":
                        print ("The bathroom is locked--your sister must be in there. Why would there be dog treats in the bathroom anyway? Please try again.")
                    
                    elif which_bedroom == "4":
                        print ("Congrats! You found the dog treats along with a note that says: 1970")
                        downstairs_again = input ("You go back downstairs, and yet again, your dogs spots you. What do you do?\n1. Walk down anyway\n2. Give him the dog treats\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the specific application your code block and if conditions might be different, but from your example it would be something akin to this.

```
answered=False
while(not answered):
    if answer=='1':
        answered=True
        print('Right answer')
    elif answer=='2':
        print('Wrong answer try again')
    else:
        print('Invalid input try again')
```

EDIT:
I'm assuming your function `input()` is handling all UI inputs behind the scenes.

```
answered=False
while(not answered):
    which_bedroom = input('....') #insert your long string 
    if which_bedroom=='1':
        print('wrong answer try again')
    elif which_bedroom =='2':
        print('wrong answer try again')
    elif which_bedroom == '3':
        answered=True
        print('correct! next question...')
    else:
        print('Invalid input try again')

next_question() #copy above for downstairs_again instead of nesting it in this loop
```

Since you created a new variable for your second question after your first question is correctly answered, I assume you have completely different if-else conditions for your next question. I'd therefore recommend implementing a similar while loop for the new question if your text-dungeon-crawler-esque adventure is relatively short and you're just trying to get a proof of concept.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, thank you! Could you look at my edit, please?

Comment: @anon_misid What goes inside the while loop will depend on how you're requesting the input from the user. If you're requesting it via a key press you'll need to wait for a new key at the beginning of every loop. Mind sharing how The variable `which_bedroom` got its string?

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a while loop:

```py
while (answer := input("QUESTION: ") != "1":
    print("Wrong answer. Try again" if answer == "2" else "Invalid input: Please try again")
```

Without the fancy stuff:

```py
answer = None
while answer != "1":
    answer = input("QUESTION: ")
    if answer == "2":
        print ("Wrong answer. Try again")
    else:
        print ("Invalid input: Please try again")
```

EDIT:  Here's what your code will look like using the above:

```py
print ("\nYou do not have any dogs treats. Maybe you should have grabbed some--your mother always keeps the dog treats in one of the bedrooms upstairs.")

while (next_choice := input("\nWhat do you do now?\n1. Go back upstairs and get the dog treats\n2. Walk down anyway\n")) != "1":
    if next_choice == "2":
        print("whatever you want to print after picking 2")

print("whatever you want to print after picking 1")

while (which_bedroom := input ("\nYou go back upstairs to look for the dog treats. Which room do you go to first?\n1. Your bedroom\n2. Your sister's bedroom\n3. The bathroom\n4. Your mother's bedroom\n")) != "4":
    if which_bedroom == "1":
        print ("This is where you first started. There is nothing here. Please try again.")

    elif which_bedroom == "2":
        print ("There is nothing here. Please try again.")

    elif which_bedroom == "3":
        print ("The bathroom is locked--your sister must be in there. Why would there be dog treats in the bathroom anyway? Please try again.")

print ("Congrats! You found the dog treats along with a note that says: 1970")

while (downstairs_again := input ("You go back downstairs, and yet again, your dogs spots you. What do you do?\n1. Walk down anyway\n2. Give him the dog treats\n")) != "correct choice":
    pass #do stuff
```

`while` loops are an easy way to accomplish this, but look into using classes holding objects of the same class to easily build and execute a tree of choices.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I appreciate it! Could you look at my edit, please?

Comment: I just did and edited my answer.  I would suggest you consider using classes instead of a million `while` loops though.